# How can I show mActionBar when it's invisible, and hide it when it's visible?

Tags: android

My current code only shows mActionBar.
How can I switch it hide or show back and force?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
            mActionBar.show();
}else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    WebView  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.goBack();
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ActionBar` has an `isShowing()` method, you can use this to check if it is currently visible or not, and decide whether it needs to be shown or hidden. This code *should* work, but I haven't tested it.

```
private void toggleActionBar() {
    if (mActionBar.isShowing()) {
        mActionBar.hide();
    }
    else {
        mActionBar.show();
    }
}
```

Then you can replace `mActionBar.show()` in your code snippet to instead call `toggleActionBar()`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Don't forget to check the docs, that's all I did :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html